# How can I use unpivot for a two table join with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]    INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT              DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The CreatedBy and the ModifiedBy in the Phrase table are both joined to the Id in the AspNetUsers table.

What I would like to do is to create a report that uses Pivot and links them so it looks like this:

```
LastName   CreatedByQty  ModifiedQty

ad1        100           50
ad2        10             5
ad3        200           99
```

I have used unpivot for a single table but never for a two table join like this. Would appreciate some advice that would help me to get the report like one above.

**Serge's answer** - I tried this but it gives a completely wrong output :-( Adding the output here and will add a comment in the suggested answer:

```
1024    420172  420172
1025    0   0
1   360328  360328
2   1331368 1331368
3   29574   29574
1023    484800  484800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `LEFT JOIN`'s and `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT   u.LastName
        ,COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pc.PhraseId),0) AS CreatedByQty
        ,COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT pm.PhraseId),0) AS ModifiedByQty
FROM dbo.AspNetUsers u
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pc
        ON u.Id = pc.CreatedBy
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Phrase pm
        ON u.Id = pm.ModifiedBy
GROUP BY u.LastName
```

Use `COALESCE` to return `0` instead of NULL if a user did not create/modify any phrases.

Comment: Hello, I tried your suggestion but the output is completely wrong. The Id's do not show up as the LastName (question corrected) but more of a problem is the numbers are not correct. I am expecting to see numbers of around 1000-2000 for most of the columns so I think perhaps something is wrong with not having a where clause? Added the output from your query into the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Anne, i updated first column to return `LastName` and added `DISTINCT` keyword to the `COUNT` to return count of unique phrases edited.

Comment: Column 'dbo.AspNetUsers.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I fixed that and it works now. Thanks